# Issue occured while generating the key using Git bash

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, git-bash

Not able to generate the key with Git bash

giving the error Bad escape character 'ygen'

while running the key generation command ssh -keygen -t rsa -C ""

Comment: Looks like it's breaking on "ygen" part of "keygen". Looking at name I suspect some weird keyboard layout or encoding.

Answer (score 20):

The command is not

```
ssh -keygen
```

it is (without space)

```
ssh-keygen
```

ssh interprets the `e` part of `-ke` as an option to set the escape char, and `ygen` is not a valid escape char. There you go ;)